# Entity Framework - "Unable to create a constant value of type..." exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception

Can somebody help me resolve this exception:

> Test method
>   KravmagaTests.Model.Entities.StudentTest.Create_Valid_Student threw
>   exception:  System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant
>   value of type 'Kravmaga.Models.Account'. Only primitive types ('such
>   as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

I get this when I run this test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Create_Valid_Student()
{
    Student student = new Student()
    {
        Username = "username",
        Firstname = "firstname",
        Surname = "surname",
        Email = "email@gmail.com",
        Password = "password",
    };
    KravmagaContext context = new KravmagaContext();
    context.AddToAccounts(student);
    context.Save();
    bool exists = context.Accounts.Contains(student); // THIS THROWS EXCEPTION
    Assert.IsTrue(exists);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your test method this way:

```
// ...
context.Save();
int newStudentId = student.Id;
// because the Id generated by the DB is available after SaveChanges

bool exists = context.Accounts.Any(a => a.Id == newStudentId);
Assert.IsTrue(exists);
```

`Contains` doesn't work here because it checks if a particular object instance is in the `context.Accounts` set. Translation of this check into SQL is not supported, only for primitive types (like the exception says). `Any` just translates the filter expression you specify into SQL and passes it to the database.

Comment: @Iškuda: BTW, what are you testing there? Is `context` some selfwritten wrapper around an `ObjectContext` or is it directly your derived `ObjectContext`? In the latter case you aren't testing *your* code but Entity Framework itself. If `exists` would ever be `false` and you didn't get an exception from EF before you reach the `Assert` at all, EF would have a terrible bug.

Comment: Thanks! Those little differences between what works in Linq to Objects and EF can be a real bear to figure out.

Comment: @krillgar: Gert Arnold has written a great answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13352779/270591) that lists a lot of the differences.

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework is trying to translate the context.Accounts.Contains(student) into an SQL statement (e.g.: "WHERE ... IN (...)"). It cannot translate it into an SQL statement because it only knows how to handle primitive types (int, string...) hence the exception.

You are probably trying to have the EF generate an SQL statement such as:

SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

You can write such a LINQ To Entities statement as follows:

```
 var studentIds = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
 var matches = from account in context.Accounts
               where studentIds.Contains(account.Id) 
               select account;
```

For more information take a look at the following blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx

The blog post I mentioned offers a work around for the .NET 3.5 framework.