# How do I overcome an "Unable to create a constant value of type ..." exception for a simple WHERE statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I am using EF with the following definitions:

```
public class StoredFile
{
    public int StoredFileId { get; set; }
    public HashCode HashCode { get; set; }
    public string LocalName { get; set; }
    //and some more fields here...
}
```

and

```
[ComplexType]
public class HashCode
{
    public Byte [] ValueArr {get; set;}
    public override bool Equals(object o) {...}
    //some more methods to manipulate hash codes                
}
```

I am trying to get the following query to work:

```
    public bool TryGetFileInfo(MachineSafeDbDataContext dataContext, HashCode hash, out StoredFile fileInfo)
    {
        var matches = from curr in dataContext.StoredFiles where (hash.Equals(curr.HashCode)) select curr;

        if (matches.Count() == 0)
        {
            fileInfo = null;
            return false;
        }

        fileInfo = matches.First();
        return true;
    }
```

However I get the "Unable to create a constant value of type ..." exception. I guess LINQ fails to find a translation to SQL for the above WHERE statement.

I am aware of the following question: [Entity Framework - "Unable to create a constant value of type..." exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379394/entity-framework-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-exception), and of the following page by Microsoft: [Known Issues and Considerations in LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx). However, I would still like to select a file from my DB based on its hash code.

Thanks,

Edit: I should have gone over L2E limitations. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364740/linq-2-sql-or-linq-entities) has some good pointers and links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call your overridden `.Equals()` in L2E.

You can, however, drill into the `ValueArr` directly:

```
var matches = from curr in dataContext.StoredFiles 
              where (curr.HashCode.ValueArr == hash.ValueArr) 
              select curr;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was sure == won't work since it does not work on a Byte[] (you need to override the equals).

Comment: L2E handles it -- has to, since that's what a SQL TIMESTAMP maps to.